# Взаимодействия между процессами посредством почтовых ящиков

Tags: c++, массивы, char, конвертация

У меня возник вопрос. функция `WriteFile()` можеж отправить только массив чар. А если мне надо передать туда массив `int`? ЧТо мне тогда делать? если какой то аналог такой функции? 
   Или подскажите, как я могу преобразовать массив `int` состоящий из чисел в `char`, а потом обратно, на стороне сервера?
   Массив чар может быть из многжества чисел разной длинны.

client: Где вместо nch, который чар, Мне нужно передать массив int[]

```
    if (0 == WriteFile(ServerMailslot, nch, strlen(nch), &BytesWritten, NULL)) {
    printf("Запись в ящик с ошибкой %lu.\n", GetLastError());
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(ServerMailslot);
    return (NULL);
}
```

server: Который должен как то принят массив int[]

```
 char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // буфер для чтения из ящика
 DWORD BytesRead; // количество прочитанных байтов
 ReadFile(SingleMailslot , buffer, BUFFER_SIZE , &BytesRead, NULL ) ;
```

Comment: Какой это язык?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk c++, забыл указать, прошу прощения)

Comment: Байты они и есть байты. В каждом `int` (элементе вашего массива) `sizeof(int)` байтов. Умножьте на количество элементов массива и передавайте. А тип адреса всегда можно привести (почитайте про приведение типов), чтобы компилятор не ругался.

Comment: Если это windows то у WriteFile указатель типа (void *), поэтому буфер может быть любого типа